# sbt revolver configuration

Tags: sbt

I am using the [sbt revolver plugin](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) to drive a vert.x scala project.

Currently I manually enter the following commands in sbt:

```
set mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter")
~re-start run scala:com.something.myClass
```

How could this be delegated to the `build.sbt` file, such that I can just run `~re-start` in sbt, rather than those two commands every time?

It seems revolver [has all the relevant configuration flexibility](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver#configuration) for that, but the sbt configuration language/conventions elude me and I failed to fiddle `build.sbt` to that effect.

Comment: `I failed to fiddle to that effect.`

Comment: This is an arcane question, but not sure what you mean (?!) :)

Comment: I just liked the words, but SO complains if you comment with thumbs-up or plus-one, so I avoided getting flagged for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your settings to the `build.sbt`. It is rather simple, if you do `set <whatever-here>`, you can drop `set` and add it to the `build.sbt` directly.

For example, the `build.sbt` for your example would look like this.

**build.sbt**

```
Revolver.settings

mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Some("org.vertx.java.platform.impl.cli.Starter")

Revolver.reStartArgs := Seq("run", "scala:com.something.myClass")
```

The list of settings you can use is [in the original link of yours](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver#configuration), there are even some examples if you look down below.